# I can't pair my Apple Mouse and Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

How to add my Magic Mouse and Wireless Keyboard to OS? In Device Search doesn't recognize any of device.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me;

```
sudo rfkill list
```

See there is your Bluetooth is blocked and then:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```